# How to make it rain everywhere?

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to create a raining-effect for [my weather app](https://thewthr.app/) with CSS-only. However, even though I achieved satisfying results with the look, I can't seem to make them cover the entire screen continuously and not just random chunks of it - how would I go about this?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#background.night {
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
}

#background>.cloud {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: cloud 10s infinite alternate;
}

#background.rain>.cloud {
  opacity: .5;
}

#background>.cloud:nth-child(even) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#background.night>.cloud {
  background-color: grey;
}

#background.rain>.cloud:before,
#background.rain>.cloud:after {
  animation: rain 1s infinite linear;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 700px;
}

#background.rain>.cloud:after {
  transform: translate(50px);
}

#background.rain>.cloud:nth-child(even):before,
#background.rain>.cloud:nth-child(even):after {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@keyframes rain {
  0% {
    box-shadow: #cccccc 30px 30px, #cccccc 40px 40px, #cccccc 50px 75px, #cccccc 55px 50px, #cccccc 70px 100px, #cccccc 80px 95px, #cccccc 110px 45px, #cccccc 75px 50px, #cccccc 80px 20px, #cccccc 65px 40px, #cccccc 100px 80px, #cccccc 45px 85px, #cccccc 95px 50px, #cccccc 90px 35px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: #cccccc 30px 970px, #cccccc 40px 980px, #cccccc 50px 945px, #cccccc 55px 980px, #cccccc 70px 960px, #cccccc 80px 945px, #cccccc 110px 995px, #cccccc 75px 950px, #cccccc 80px 920px, #cccccc 65px 940px, #cccccc 100px 980px, #cccccc 45px 985px, #cccccc 95px 950px, #cccccc 90px 985px;
  }
}

@keyframes cloud {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50px) scale(1.05);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="rain night">
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -797.689px; left: -315px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -865.689px; left: -225px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -814.689px; left: -65px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -853.689px; left: 253px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -823.689px; left: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -843.689px; left: 109px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good job for some random `radial-gradient` that you repeat. Not `linear-gradient` because you will have a hard time creating spaces between repetition (maybe impossible).

Here is a basic example. We use the same gradient at different random position and all will repeat:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
  overflow:hidden;
}
html:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:calc(100% + 100px); /* should be bigger than (100% + 55px)*/
  background:
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) -12px 3px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 17px 0,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 6px  12px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 24px 23px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 39px 30px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 5px  43px;
  background-size:50px 55px;
  animation:rain 0.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rain{
  to {
     transform:translateY(55px); /* Same as the height of the background-size */
  }
}
```

And if you want a litte skewing:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
  overflow:hidden;
}
html:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-20%;
  left:-20%;
  height:calc(100% + 100px); /* should be bigger than (100% + 55px)*/
  background:
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) -12px 3px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 17px 0,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 6px  12px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 24px 23px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 39px 30px,
     radial-gradient(2px 8px,#cccccc 100%,transparent 100%) 5px  43px;
  background-size:50px 55px;
  animation:rain 0.2s linear infinite;
  transform:skew(-8deg);
}
@keyframes rain{
  to {
     transform:skew(-8deg) translateY(55px); /* Same as the height of the background-size */
  }
}
```

And with CSS variables to easily control:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
  overflow:hidden;
  
  --s:2px 8px; /* size of drop of water*/
  --c:#ccc;    /* color of the water*/
  --a:-7deg;   /* control the skewing*/
  --w:50px;    /* width of the pattern*/
  --h:55px;    /* height of the pattern*/
  
   --rad:radial-gradient(var(--s),var(--c) 100%,transparent 100%)
}
html:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-20%;
  left:-20%;
  height:calc(100% + var(--h) + 10px); /* should be bigger than (100% + var(--h))*/
  background:
     var(--rad) -12px 3px,
     var(--rad) 17px 0,
     var(--rad) 6px  12px,
     var(--rad) 24px 23px,
     var(--rad) 39px 30px,
     var(--rad) 5px  43px;
  background-size:var(--w) var(--h);
  animation:rain 0.2s linear infinite;
  transform:skew(var(--a));
}
@keyframes rain{
  to {
     transform:skew(var(--a)) translateY(var(--h)); /* Same as the height of the background-size */
  }
}
```

---

You can consider two layers with a different pattern for another kind of animation (more random)

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
  overflow:hidden;
  
  --s:2px 8px; /* size of drop of water*/
  --c:#ccc;    /* color of the water*/
  --a:-7deg;   /* control the skewing*/
  --w:53px;    /* width of the pattern*/
  --h:55px;    /* height of the pattern*/
  
   --rad:radial-gradient(var(--s),var(--c) 100%,transparent 100%)
}
html:before,
html:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-20%;
  left:-20%;
  height:calc(100% + var(--h) + 10px); /* should be bigger than (100% + var(--h))*/
  background:
     var(--rad) -12px 3px,
     var(--rad) 17px 0,
     var(--rad) 6px  12px,
     var(--rad) 24px 23px,
     var(--rad) 39px 30px,
     var(--rad) 5px  43px;
  background-size:var(--w) var(--h);
  animation:rain 0.2s linear infinite;
  transform:skew(var(--a));
}
html:after {
   --h:70px;
   --w:61px;
}
@keyframes rain{
  to {
     transform:skew(var(--a)) translateY(var(--h)); /* Same as the height of the background-size */
  }
}
```

Comment: I do like it a lot already - do you also have an idea how it could be made a bit more random? It looks a bit to symmetrical for rain

Comment: @leonheess you will need to add more gradient and play with the position. remove the animation and adjust the different values to understand the trick then you can easily create any combination

Comment: Also, how are you creating that many drops with so few radial-gradients?

Comment: @leonheess the magic of repeat ;) ... it's only a [50px 55px] pattern that I am repeating. Add `background-repeat:no-repeat` and you will see the trick

Comment: @leonheess if you are still intrested I have added another idea, more realistic and less symmetrical

Comment: Added you to the [stylesheet](https://github.com/leonheess/wthr/blob/master/public/styles.css#L281) (line 281)

Comment: @leonheess you may want to give your thoughts here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394396/8620333 ... this question and your App are involved

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing some `margin-left`

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#background.night {
  background: linear-gradient(#0F2129, #47334A);
}

#background>.cloud {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: cloud 10s infinite alternate;
}

#background.rain>.cloud {
  opacity: .5;
}

#background>.cloud:nth-child(even) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#background.night>.cloud {
  background-color: grey;
}

#background.rain>.cloud:before,
#background.rain>.cloud:after {
  animation: rain 1s infinite linear;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 700px;
  margin-left:400px;
}

#background.rain>.cloud:after {
  transform: translate(50px);
}

#background.rain>.cloud:nth-child(even):before,
#background.rain>.cloud:nth-child(even):after {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@keyframes rain {
  0% {
    box-shadow: #cccccc 30px 30px, #cccccc 40px 40px, #cccccc 50px 75px, #cccccc 55px 50px, #cccccc 70px 100px, #cccccc 80px 95px, #cccccc 110px 45px, #cccccc 75px 50px, #cccccc 80px 20px, #cccccc 65px 40px, #cccccc 100px 80px, #cccccc 45px 85px, #cccccc 95px 50px, #cccccc 90px 35px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: #cccccc 30px 970px, #cccccc 40px 980px, #cccccc 50px 945px, #cccccc 55px 980px, #cccccc 70px 960px, #cccccc 80px 945px, #cccccc 110px 995px, #cccccc 75px 950px, #cccccc 80px 920px, #cccccc 65px 940px, #cccccc 100px 980px, #cccccc 45px 985px, #cccccc 95px 950px, #cccccc 90px 985px;
  }
}

@keyframes cloud {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50px) scale(1.05);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="rain night">
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -797.689px; left: -315px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -865.689px; left: -225px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -814.689px; left: -65px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -853.689px; left: 253px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -823.689px; left: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="cloud" style="top: -843.689px; left: 109px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a slight improvement but I want the rain to be everywhere instead of random chunks dropping down

Comment: mybe the approach needs to be more dives (even created by some script) with different speeds and locations. or stay with the groups but spread the drop shadow and variant the speed. play with it